# Partial replace with sed command

Tags: linux, bash, sed, replace, ksh

We have a filewith some utf-16 decimal characters and we would like to replace them in the following manner

```
Test Line in a file \u343- ? some random words  \u1233? 300 \u241? \u208?\cell
```

The required out put is

```
Test Line in a file \u343- ? some random words  UTF16-1233| 300 UTF16-241| UTF16-208|\cell
```

The requirement is to change **\u[0-9]+?** to **UTF16-[0-9]+|**
Replace the initial \u to UTF16- and the ending ? with a pipe |.
Please note if there is any non digit character between \u and ? it should not be considered

Comment: Wait, does `\u1233` is stored in file as a single utf character, as 2 bytes or these are 6 separate characters, 6 bytes?

Comment: 6 separate characters. but the length may vary like \u241 would be 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using sed to modify the file in place, you can:

- Match `\\u([0-9]+)\?`:

  Match a literal `\u`, match and capture one or more digits, match a literal `?`.
- Replace `UTF16-\1`:

  Replace with the string `UTF16-` followed by the captured group.

---

```
$ sed -i -E 's/\\u([0-9]+)\?/UTF16-\1|/g' file
$ cat file
Test Line in a file \u343- ? some random words  UTF16-1233| 300 UTF16-241| UTF16-208|\cell
```

Comment: Thanks you Paolo. This is what I was looking for. :)